# Wifi signal weak Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW

Tags: release-juno, wifi, intel

I have install Elementary OS 5 Juno and i notice that wifi signal very weak even though still can connect to it and use it like normal. But sometime it will affect my work due to unstable signal.

I have tried to disable power management but it won't help much on getting better wifi signal.

any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

It is worth trying the solution described [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ls3sE64Ril8). The video also shows a way of measuring the speed from Terminal, using speedtest. So, install and run speedtest to see the down/up speed before applying the solution:

```
sudo apt install speedtest-cli && speedtest
```

Now, in Terminal paste the following commands, one after the other:

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv iwlmvm
sudo modprobe -rfv iwlwifi
sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi
```

Run `speedtest` again and compare the results.

Comment: My wifi signal is weak but the speed quite high (not sure why). The speed is fast in 5ghz but after i run those command above, my speed limited to 30mbps or below. Why?